# How to calculate the string 'yyyymm' into the string 'yyyymm -1' ex: calculate '201401' into '201312' in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql

How to calculate  the string `'yyyymm'` into the string `'yyyymm -1'`

Ex: calculate  `'201401'` into `'201312'` in T-SQL?

Comment: please also add, what did you try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 declare @x char(6) = '201401'
 select convert(char(6), dateadd(month, -1, @x + '01'), 112)
```